# Can we setSelection in flex UITextField without focus

Tags: apache-flex

I want to set background color for specified range of text in UITextField. So Itried using setSelection. But it need focus. Any one please help. Can we set selection without focus.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextField.alwaysShowSelection` property.